# java cannot resolve symbol 'param' while using mockMvc to test spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, junit5, mockmvc

I am trying to test my spring boot application by using junit5 and mockMvc, however i cannot even compile it because java cannot resolve the symbol param.
Can anyone please tell me what i can do to find the missing package?

I am using IDEA to do the development.
I think i need to import some package of mockMvc, however i cannot figure out which one i have missed.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class EmployeeServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Test
    void testInsert() throws Exception{
        mockMvc.perform(post("/add"))
                .param("id", 999)
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
        ArrayList<Employee> tmpList = (ArrayList<Employee>)employeeRepository.findEmp(999);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry this is kind of stupid, it should be mockMvc.perform(post("/add").param("id", 999))